# C# Make List of dictionaries in List dynamically and populate/retrieve values

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I read a parameters file who has sections and under each section a parameter, an equal sign and a value. For example:

```
[users]
Nick=twelve
John=eleven
Mary=twentynine

[stations]
pc1=on
pc2=on
pc3=off
pc4=off

[grades]
a=distinction
b=good
c=pass

etc..
```

I am trying to make a List of Dictionaries, since by definition I do not have repetitions of parameters' names (for example, parameter "pc1" can appear in any, but only one, section - for example above, it exists in section "[stations]" etc.) and populate as well as retrieve the data.

For example:

```
MyList.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>()); // "users" - how do I name the dictionary dynamically, as I read the section name?
MyList.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>()); // "stations"
```

etc.

The objective I am trying to achieve, is to query the list, knowing the dictionary name and the key, and retrieve the value if the key exists.

```
string JohnCode = MyList("users", "John")    //if key "John" exists in users Dictionary
```

NOTE: I do NOT know beforehand the names and how many sections are in my data. All I know is that sections are in brackets, i.e. [namehere] and then always follow key-value pairs as above..
Assume every key-pair is a string.

Can you help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This looks a lot like an ini file. Are you already able to read the file and parse it, the question is just making a dictionary(s) to hold it?

Comment: What you probably want is a dictionary of dictionaries.  The Key to the outer dictionary is the name of the INI file section.  The inner dictionary is the key/value pairs in each section.  Something like `var iniDict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>()`

Comment: YES you are absolutely correct, it's actually an .ini file. I read the file each time, but the .ini file changes - I mean, the section names as well as the key-pair values of course.

Comment: @Flydog57 - Thank you, also a dictionary of dictionaries would be fine. My problem is how to name the dictionaries as objects - for example, later, I will have a string like "users" and a key like "Nick" and I will have to search IF a dictionary with that name ("users") exists, and then lookup the key ("Nick").. Otherwise I will have to iterate all dictionaries !!

Comment: I thought parsing INI files in c# was a solved problem already..

Comment: @CaiusJard Weeeellll, yes and no :) Seems Microsoft would prefer to read ini in an XML format, on the other hand there is a Nuget pack but has a problem if the value contains '=' and, it's complicated if the sections appear more than once.. But nonetheless it's an interesting thing solving it dynamically..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a unique `Dictionary<string, string>` to store the values of each section as indicated in the comments on another answer, is there any reason you have to use a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`? Because it seems like you'd be able to solve this with a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>`.

The `key` of the `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>` is the section name. The `value` would be a `Dictionary<string, string>` containing the values under that section.

```cs
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> sections = 
    new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();

sections.Add("users", new Dictionary<string, string>>());
sections.Add("stations", new Dictionary<string, string>>());
sections["users"].Add("Nick", "twelve");
sections["stations"].Add("pc1", "on"); 

string Nick = sections["users"]["Nick"]; // Nick = "twelve"
string pc1 = sections["stations"]["pc1"]; // pc1 = "on"
```

You could use an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) to `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>` to handle searching safely. For example:

```
public static class IniExtensions
{
    public static bool TryGetSectionValue(
        this Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> src,
        string section, string key, out string value)
    {
        value = null;
        if (src.TryGetValue(section, out Dictionary<string, string> sectionValues))
        {
            return sectionValues.TryGetValue(key, out value);
        }
        return false;
    }
}

Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> sections = 
    new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();

sections.Add("users", new Dictionary<string, string>>());
sections.Add("stations", new Dictionary<string, string>>());
sections["users"].Add("Nick", "twelve");
sections["stations"].Add("pc1", "on"); 

// This returns true, and the Nick variable will have a value of "twelve"
sections.TryGetSectionValue("users", "Nick", out string Nick);

// this returns false, and the value variable has a value of null
sections.TryGetSectionValue("No Section", "Nick", out string value);

// this returns false, and the Joey variable has a value of null
sections.TryGetSectionValue("users", "Joey", out string Joey);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I think that's also the point made before by Flydog57 and your solution holds: no specific reason for a List (and probably faster..)

Comment: I think you nailed it. Bravo. Just a note, I think last line will actually return "eleven" since "John" is a parameter present in "users" section, am I right? Nonetheless, it's a really elegant code, thank you very much, this is it.

Comment: Kindly ignore my question above, I understood the concept. Brilliant and thanks again!

Comment: @Nick:  This is exactly what I was talking about, right down to the `TryGetSectionValue` method +1

Comment: If you're planning on exposing this via a public API, a variation on this would be to formalize the relationships by creating a custom `ParameterDictionary` which derives from `Dictionary<string, string>`, but also has e.g. a `Section` property on it. You could then create a `SectionCollection` which derives from `KeyedCollection<ParameterDictionary>`. The syntax would be identical to @Joshua's answer, but it would formalize the semantics and give you space to create first-class overloads for setting or retrieving by section and parameter key, potentially including a composite indexer.

Comment: To build off of my previous comment, I put a similar approach in place for [a specialized multimap class](https://github.com/OnTopicCMS/OnTopic-Library/blob/master/OnTopic/Collections/Specialized/TopicMultiMap.cs), which allows for grouped collections of a local entity object (`Topic`). Though, in that case, the underlying collection isn't a dictionary. The basic premise still applies.

Comment: @JeremyCaney Your solution is brilliant but somehow complicated.. The problem that I didn't noticed above, is that I don't try to VALIDATE a value but I am SEARCHING a value.. In the above solution unfortunately it's like I have the section, the parameter and the value, and I am asking to see if it's true or not.. Anyhow, I will try to refactor.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that your section and keys only allow certain characters. Use that to your advantage and make a single Dictionary where the Key is the combination of the file's section and key.

In this example, I'll use a pipe `|` to separate the segments in the Dictionary Key.

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
data.Add("users|Nick", "twelve");
//...
data.Add("stations|pc1", "on");
//...
data.Add("grades|a", "distinction");
//...
```

Now when you want to lookup an entry, you lookup by *both* section and key ("users|Nick").

This however requires all entries to be part of a section. If you need to, as you read the ini file you can keep a seperate list of the section names to assist you with doing lookups later.

---

While it's a bit more expensive than having individual Dictionaries per section, you can still query the data.

To get a distinct list of all sections:

```
var sectionNames = data
    .Select(x => x.Key.Split('|')[0])
    .Distinct();
```

To get all entries in a section

```
var sectionName = "users";
var entriesInUsersSection = data
    .Where(x => x.Key.StartsWith(sectionName + "|"));
```

And more Linq manipulations are possible.

Comment: this is a brilliant idea. I cannot refuse it, it will work. I would really prefer though if I could have separate dictionaries (that's why I was trying to put them in a List) so that I can iterate them a bit more easily and also making it a tat easier to read. Thank you !

Comment: It's very interesting and it works, I'm just not sure on the pipe character and frankly I would like to avoid guessing although your logic is correct.